# Assign mobile application to user directly using Microsoft Graph beta API(Intune)

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, intune

There is the application flow:

1. Admin uploads a mobile application(mobileAppId) as a blob to the Intune web Portal and configures it.
2. User X(Non-Admin) using his mobile device has to install a mobileAppId to his or selected User's(targetUserId) mobile device which was enrolled as well. He(User X) should have the ability to click the button "Install". After clicking the request should be created and sent to the Microsoft Graph API(Intune) or any other(if exists) API. API should send the notification back to the targetUserId's device. After the confirmation message about starting the application installation process should be shown on a mobile device.

I found the Intune beta API [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/intune_apps_app_conceptual). It contains the [assign](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_apps_mobileapp_assign) method which assigns the application(mobileAppId) to the Azure AD user group(targetGroupId). This method works fine for Non-Admin users and can be called from enrolled(in Company Portal) mobile devices. However it does not contain any targetUserId parameter.

**The question is:**
How to assign the application mobileAppId to the current or selected User (targetUserId) directly without targetGroupId? Does Microsoft Graph API(Intune) support this functionality?

PS: I am not comfortable with creating of personal group for each user in Azure AD :)

Answer (score 0):

I am part of the Microsoft Intune team, specifically working on the integration between Microsoft Intune and Microsoft Graph.

Currently Intune only supports assigning apps to Azure AD groups, the same applies for other assignable entities (for example device configurations). I would recommend that you give your feedback about supporting assigning to users at the [Microsoft Intune UserVoice](https://microsoftintune.uservoice.com) site.

Hope that helps

Peter

Comment: Will do it. Thank you for the advice.